# DAX : Calculating average Headcount YTD using existing Headcount measure

Tags: dax

I need to get the average headcount YTD for a fiscal year report using an existing measure that calculates headcount per month.

`Headcount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(PersonDetails[PERSON NUMBER]), FILTER(VALUES(PersonDetails[WORK RELATIONSHIP START DATE]), PersonDetails[WORK RELATIONSHIP START DATE] <=MAX(DimDates[Date])), FILTER(VALUES(PersonDetails[TERMINATION DATE 2]), OR(PersonDetails[TERMINATION DATE 2] >=MAX(DimDates[Date]),ISBLANK(PersonDetails[TERMINATION DATE 2]))))+0`

As it stands I need the average monthly headcount figures from Apr23 to Jul23 when FY24 slicer is selected. In my screen shot of the measure in a Table visual, the **AVG. YTD Headcount** measure isn't coming back with the correct average for Apr - Jul it should be **11085** and not 11033.

The measure(s) behind the **AVG. YTD Headcount**

`Monthly Avg. Headcount =  AVERAGEX(VALUES(DimDates[Month & Year]), [Headcount])`

`YTD Avg. Headcount =  CALCULATE( [Monthly Avg. Headcount], FILTER(ALL (DimDates), DimDates[Month & Year] <= MAX(DimDates[Month & Year]) && DimDates[Month & Year] = MAX(DimDates[Month & Year])))`

I used a method by Enterprise DNA

Can anyone help with this as I'm totally stumped!